# Como selecionar/encontrar aspas de abertura e fechamento em uma string utilizando regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Passada uma string devo aplicar uma regex que selecione as aspas de abertura e fechamento, ignorando qualquer ocorrência de aspas no escopo interno da string. Veja alguns exemplos:

```
"Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento"
'Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento'
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência interna 'de aspas simples' e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência escapada \"de aspas duplas\" e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
Essa string não tem aspas de abertura e fechamento, então deve ser ignorada
Essa string tem aspas aqui', porém, como não é no inicio e no fim, deve ser ignorada
```

Essa abordagem irá me permitir aplicar alguns match de validação, bem como permitir remover estas aspas já que este é um dos meus objetivos.

Sendo assim, de forma resumida, como posso utilizar regex para selecionar as aspas que envolvem uma string, sendo elas simples ou duplas?

> Existe uma outra regra que é: caso a string inicie e finalize com um padrão de aspas diferente o match não deve ser verdadeiro/ocorrer. Ex:

```
'Não deve selecionar as aspas pois abertura e encerramento são diferentes"
```

O único resultado que consegui obter foi `(?:^["']|["']$)`, porém, não atende conforme descrevi.

Comment: se a string tem sempre aquele formato, pode remover o primeiro e último caracteres da string, usando `substring` e nem precisa de um *regex*

Comment: Complementei a publicação para ficar mais completa. Nem todas as string possuem aspas de abertura e fechamento.

Comment: Como é passada essa string para o programa? Cada linha é um elemento num array ou tudo é um texto só? Pergunto porque dependendo da estrutura a resposta é diferente.

Comment: É passado como string única. A função que faz esse parse/tratamento recebe uma string literal toda vez que é chamada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Obtendo o conteúdo entre aspas

Se você tem exatamente uma frase por linha, não precisa de regex. Basta usar [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para separar as linhas e depois ver se cada linha começa e termina com aspas:

```js
const texto = `"Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento"
'Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento'
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência interna 'de aspas simples' e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência escapada \\"de aspas duplas\\" e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Aspas de abertura diferente do fechamento'
Essa string não tem aspas de abertura e fechamento, então deve ser ignorada
Essa string tem aspas aqui ', porém, como não é no inicio e no fim, deve ser ignorada`;

for (const linha of texto.split('\n')) {
    let primeiro = linha[0]; // primeiro caractere da linha
    let ultimo = linha.slice(-1); // último caractere da linha
    // se começa com aspas e termina com a mesma aspas
    if ((primeiro === '"' || primeiro === "'") && primeiro === ultimo) {
        // pega o texto entre as aspas
        console.log(linha.slice(1, -1));
    }
}
```

Se a string tiver quebras de linha do Windows (`\r\n`), você pode trocar para `texto.split(/[\r\n]+/)` (assim, ele considera um ou mais `\r` ou `\n` em sequência).

---

Claro que também pode ser feito com regex. A sua não funcionou porque ela só verifica se começa com aspas **ou** termina com aspas (apenas uma dessas condições é o suficiente). Além disso, ela não garante que as aspas de abertura são a mesma do fechamento (poderia começar com `"` e terminar com `'` ou vice-versa).

Com regex ficaria assim:

```js
const texto = `"Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento"
'Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento'
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência interna 'de aspas simples' e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência escapada \\"de aspas duplas\\" e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Aspas de abertura diferente do fechamento'
Essa string não tem aspas de abertura e fechamento, então deve ser ignorada
Essa string tem aspas aqui ', porém, como não é no inicio e no fim, deve ser ignorada`;

let r = /^(["'])(.+)\1$/gm;
for (const match of texto.matchAll(r)) {
    console.log(match[2]); // pega somente o texto entre as aspas
}
```

Primeiro eu coloco as aspas de abertura entre parênteses, formando um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (e como é o primeiro par de parênteses da expressão, então é o primeiro grupo). No final eu uso a [*back-reference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1`, que significa "o mesmo que foi capturado no grupo 1", assim eu garanto que as aspas de abertura e fechamento devem ser a mesma.

Também uso os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam o início e fim da string, mas graças à [*flag* `m`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags), eles também indicam o início e fim de uma linha. Assim eu garanto que as aspas devem estar no início e fim da linha.

No meio eu coloco `.+`, que indica "um ou mais caracteres", e dentro de parênteses para formar outro grupo de captura (no caso, é o grupo 2).

Também uso a *flag* `g` para pegar todas as ocorrências e dentro do `for` eu imprimo o conteúdo do grupo 2 (que é o texto que está entre as aspas). Se quiser todo o texto, incluindo as aspas, use `match[0]`.

---

[`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) pode não funcionar em browsers mais antigos, então uma alternativa é usar [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```js
const texto = `"Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento"
'Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento'
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência interna 'de aspas simples' e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência escapada \\"de aspas duplas\\" e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Aspas de abertura diferente do fechamento'
Essa string não tem aspas de abertura e fechamento, então deve ser ignorada
Essa string tem aspas aqui ', porém, como não é no inicio e no fim, deve ser ignorada`;

let r = /^(["'])(.+)\1$/gm;
let match;
while (match = r.exec(texto)) {
    console.log(match[2]); // pega somente o texto entre as aspas
}
```

---

Mas se **não** for uma frase por linha, aí fica um pouco mais complicado:

```js
const texto = `"Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento" blablabla 'Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento' lorem ipsum "Deve ignorar essa ocorrência interna 'de aspas simples' e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string" fdsafadsf asd "Deve ignorar essa ocorrência escapada \\"de aspas duplas\\" e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string" fdasfasdfdsa Essa string não tem aspas de abertura e fechamento, então deve ser ignorada
Essa string tem aspas aqui ', porém, como não é no inicio e no fim, deve ser ignorada`;

let r = /"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)"|'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)+)'/g;
for (const match of texto.matchAll(r)) {
    if (match[0][0] === '"') {
        console.log(match[1]); // pega somente o texto entre as aspas
    } else {
        console.log(match[2]);
    }
}
```

A ideia é pegar as aspas, e no meio eu posso ter `[^"\\]|\\.`:

- `[^"\\]`: um caractere que não seja aspas nem `\`, **ou**
- `\\.`: um `\` seguido de qualquer caractere (assim ele pega os escapes)

Eu faço o mesmo para as aspas simples. O conteúdo entre as aspas estará no grupo 1 ou 2, dependendo das aspas que forem pegas.

Esse caso só não detecta quando tem aspas de abertura e fechamento diferentes no meio do texto (por exemplo, `bla "abc' xyz`), pois aí fica impossível detectar se as aspas diferentes fazem parte da mesma frase ou não, e terá muitos falsos positivos (uma delas pode ser considerada a abertura ou fechamento de outra aspas que aparece antes ou depois, e aí teria que ter algum outro critério para separar as frases).

---

---

### Removendo as aspas

Agora se a ideia é remover as aspas, basta fazer umas modificações.

Com `split`:

```js
const texto = `"Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento"
'Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento'
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência interna 'de aspas simples' e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência escapada \\"de aspas duplas\\" e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Aspas de abertura diferente do fechamento'
Essa string não tem aspas de abertura e fechamento, então deve ser ignorada
Essa string tem aspas aqui ', porém, como não é no inicio e no fim, deve ser ignorada`;

let novoTexto = '';
for (const linha of texto.split(/(\n)/)) {
    let primeiro = linha[0]; // primeiro caractere da linha
    let ultimo = linha.slice(-1); // último caractere da linha
    // se começa com aspas e termina com a mesma aspas
    if ((primeiro === '"' || primeiro === "'") && primeiro === ultimo) {
        // pega o texto entre as aspas
        novoTexto += linha.slice(1, -1);
    } else novoTexto += linha;
}
console.log(novoTexto);
```

Eu faço o `split` usando `(\n)` (pois quando há um grupo de captura na regex, as quebras de linha são incluídas no resultado). Assim eu consigo concatenar as quebras de linha da string original.

---

E com regex:

```js
const texto = `"Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento"
'Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento'
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência interna 'de aspas simples' e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Deve ignorar essa ocorrência escapada \\"de aspas duplas\\" e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string"
"Aspas de abertura diferente do fechamento'
Essa string não tem aspas de abertura e fechamento, então deve ser ignorada
Essa string tem aspas aqui ', porém, como não é no inicio e no fim, deve ser ignorada`;

let novoTexto = texto.replace(/^(["'])(.+)\1$/gm, '$2');
console.log(novoTexto);
```

No `replace` eu uso `$2`, que corresponde ao segundo grupo de captura (que no caso, é o conteúdo entre as aspas).

Para o caso de não ter uma frase em cada linha:

```js
const texto = `"Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento" blablabla 'Deve selecionar as aspas de abertura e fechamento' lorem ipsum "Deve ignorar essa ocorrência interna 'de aspas simples' e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string" fdsafadsf asd "Deve ignorar essa ocorrência escapada \\"de aspas duplas\\" e selecionar somente as de abertura e fechamento da string" fdasfasdfdsa Essa string não tem aspas de abertura e fechamento, então deve ser ignorada
Essa string tem aspas aqui ', porém, como não é no inicio e no fim, deve ser ignorada`;

let novoTexto = texto.replace(/"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)"|'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)+)'/g, '$1$2');
console.log(novoTexto);
```

Como o conteúdo entre aspas pode estar no grupo 1 ou 2, eu uso `$1$2` (o grupo que não ocorrer estará vazio, por isso assim funciona).

Comment: Consigo utilizar em um replace no meu código typescript para remover somente as aspas que casam com essa regex?

Comment: @FábioJânio Atualizei a resposta